# Background process limit in developer options doesn't work on Samsung Galaxy S10

Tags: settings, developer-options, samsung-galaxy-s-10

I'm using debloated Samsung Galaxy S10. When I set the background limit to any number or none, it doesnt work. I checked the cached process in running services, there are more than 5 apps.

Oh these are 3rd party apps. Im wondering if my phone is messed up since the settings I set it to isnt functioning.

Any solution?

Comment: I am not sure but I would assume that the background limitation only affects third party apps. Apps by Samsung (or to be precise system apps) are usually not affected by any limitations you can set in the Android settings.